# how to forward/redirect request for one port to another port

Tags: apache, port, portforwarding

Is it possible that a http request for one port be forwarded or redirected to another port. A request like this

```
http://localhost:8080
```

be forwarded to another port say 8181. And blocks all the requests for the default port say 80. I am on linux machine having apache running.

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

hey hii user,
             You can configure it from apache using NameVirtualHost directive and additional ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives provided by `mod_proxy` module. Here is a basic configuration.

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
ProxyPass / http://localhost:81/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:81/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mydomain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain2
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why it is not redirecting to port 8080.

Can you spot the error?

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ServerName ofornecedor.com.br
    ServerAlias http://ofornecedor.com.br

    ProxyPass /admin/event ws://localhost:8080/admin/event
    ProxyPassReverse /admin/event ws://localhost:8080/admin/event

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>


apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-07-30 11:46:14 UTC; 8s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 14742 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11742 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14811 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 55
   Memory: 6.5M
      CPU: 61ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─14828 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─14831 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─14832 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jul 30 11:46:13 ip-172-31-13-126 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Jul 30 11:46:13 ip-172-31-13-126 apache2[14811]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Jul 30 11:46:13 ip-172-31-13-126 apache2[14811]: [Mon Jul 30 11:46:13.480124 2018] [so:warn] [pid 14827:tid 139956103014272] AH01574: module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
Jul 30 11:46:13 ip-172-31-13-126 apache2[14811]: [Mon Jul 30 11:46:13.480178 2018] [so:warn] [pid 14827:tid 139956103014272] AH01574: module proxy_http_module is already loaded, skipping
Jul 30 11:46:14 ip-172-31-13-126 apache2[14811]:  *
Jul 30 11:46:14 ip-172-31-13-126 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```